# check if class exsit before including - wordpress (functions.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

Was Coding a Wordpress theme from the scratch and i made JS Composer include-able as a must install plugin, however i was thinking, not every one would need it, thus some may install it and some may single ignore it, but the bad side of it all is that i am calling it as a function class in the fucntions.php file which would generate an error because I haven't installed the js composer Wordpress plugin.

had tried every possible means to brain storm this, please I need your ideals.

Comment: Every possible means except the PHP manual? : http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Comment: thanks, i was way up my head, ddint tink abt dat